# How to obtain and auto display visitor's geolocation data(country) on dropdown for woocommerce shop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation

I have no idea on how to output the geolocation of the user on a WP with woocommerce installed. 
From my research  I need to use the geolocate_ip function 
https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Geo_IP.html

I have tried this, but it cannot find the function. I am sure that I have no clue what I am doing.

```
<?php 
$glctest = geolocate_ip( $ip_address = 'get_ip_address()', $fallback = true );
echo $glctest;} ?>
```

Aside from this, the next thing I am trying to learn is how to default the country in a dropdown form based on his geolocation. If someone can show me how to do this it would be really great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$e = new WC_Geolocation();
echo $e->get_ip_address();
?>
```

Check this out.!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Geo IP on your server or site.  If not you could use wp-geoip-detect and the in the settings download the current GEO IP lite database.

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/geoip-detect/

This it what I currently use and it should make this function work.
Once installed I can get the required information required for Geo targeting

```
i.e. $record = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
     $this->countryCode = $record->country->isoCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the users location as in country or state you can use the below method...

`$wcg = new WC_Geolocation(); 
echo '<pre>', print_r($wcg->geolocate_ip(), true), '</pre>';`

The official documentation for this WC_Geolocation class can be found here:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Geolocation.html

Comment: The array that is returned does not include the state.  The array that is returned looks like this:  return array( 'country' => $country_code, 'state'   => '', );.  You can see the details here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Geolocation.html#139-189